# JQuery onChangeDate event change date manually

Tags: jquery, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I have 2 `datepickers` in my page and i want to have 1 year range between them.
So far whenever one of them change, i check the other's one value and i update it accorndingly.

```
$("#DateFrom").datepicker().on("changeDate", function () {
  var dt = new Date($(this).val());
  dt.setFullYear(dt.getFullYear() + 1)
  var updateDate = new Date(dt);

  var dateFrom =$(this).val();
  var dateTo = $("#DateTo").val();

  if (new Date(dateFrom).getTime() > new Date(dateTo).getTime())
      $('#DateTo').val('');

  if (new Date(dateTo).getTime() > new Date(updateDate).getTime())
      $('#DateTo').datepicker('setDate', updateDate);
});


$("#DateTo").datepicker().on("changeDate", function (e) {
  var dt = new Date($(this).val());
  dt.setFullYear(dt.getFullYear() - 1)
  var updateDate = new Date(dt);

  var dateTo = $(this).val();
  var dateFrom = $("#DateFrom").val();

  if (new Date(dateFrom).getTime() > new Date(dateTo).getTime()) {
      $('#DateFrom').val('');
  }

  if (new Date(dateFrom).getTime() < new Date(updateDate).getTime()) {
      $('#DateFrom').datepicker('setDate', updateDate); 
  }
});
```

It works fine if you select a date from the `datepicker`, but if you try to type it manually the event fires whenever you type something and it calculates a wrong date.

For example, if the `#DateFrom` values is `01/01/2016` and i change it manually to `'01/01/2015'` when i delete the 5 the event will take the current date as `01/01/201` and it will calculate the updateDate as `01/01/202`.

Is there any way to trigger the event after the user finish typing?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is that a jquery UI or a bootstrap datepicker ?

Comment: @GilleQ. it's a bootstrap-datepicker...i added the appropriate tag also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, It seems that i solved it by changing these lines from

```
$("#DateFrom").focusout(function () 
$("#DateTo").focusout(function ()
```

to

```
$("#DateFrom").focusout(function () 
$("#DateTo").focusout(function ()
```

The `.focusout()` event seems to work well whether the user selects the date from datepicker or he types it manually.

**If anyone has a better implementation please post it.**